# Ошибка "Нарушение прав доступа при чтении..."

Tags: c++, directx

Подскажите, еже ли кто понимает: выдает сообщение "Нарушение прав доступа при чтении" в строке, помеченной ***ВОТ ЗДЕСЬ ПРОБЛЕМА!!!****

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <d3d11.h>
#include <d3dx11.h>
#include <d3dcompiler.h>
#include <xnamath.h>
#include "resource.h"
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Structures
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

class Model
{
private:
    //Model model;
public:
    Model();
    struct SimpleVertex
    {
        XMFLOAT3 Pos;
    };
    bool Init(ID3D11Device* ,ID3D11DeviceContext*);
    ID3D11Buffer*           g_pVertexBuffer;
}model;
Model::Model()
{
    g_pVertexBuffer=NULL;
};

bool Model::Init(ID3D11Device *g_pd3dDevice,ID3D11DeviceContext* g_pImmediateContext)
{
        SimpleVertex *vertices;
        vertices=new SimpleVertex[4];

        ifstream fin;
        fin.open("tr.mdl");
        float x,y,z;

        for(int i=0;i<=2;i++)
        {
            fin>>x;fin>>y;fin>>z;
            vertices[i].Pos=XMFLOAT3(x,y,z);
        }

        fin.close();

    D3D11_BUFFER_DESC bd;
    ZeroMemory( &bd, sizeof(bd) );
    bd.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
    bd.ByteWidth = sizeof( SimpleVertex ) * 3;
    bd.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_VERTEX_BUFFER;
    bd.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
    D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA InitData;
    ZeroMemory( &InitData, sizeof(InitData) );
    InitData.pSysMem = vertices;
    g_pd3dDevice->CreateBuffer( &bd, &InitData, &g_pVertexBuffer ); //ВОТ ЗДЕСЬ ПРОБЛЕМА!!!

    // Set vertex buffer
    UINT stride = sizeof( SimpleVertex );
    UINT offset = 0;
    g_pImmediateContext->IASetVertexBuffers( 0, 1, &g_pVertexBuffer, &stride, &offset );

    // Set primitive topology
    g_pImmediateContext->IASetPrimitiveTopology( D3D11_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLELIST );
    return true;
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Global Variables
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
HINSTANCE               g_hInst = NULL;
HWND                    g_hWnd = NULL;
D3D_DRIVER_TYPE         g_driverType = D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_NULL;
D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL       g_featureLevel = D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0;
ID3D11Device*           g_pd3dDevice = NULL;
ID3D11DeviceContext*    g_pImmediateContext = NULL;
IDXGISwapChain*         g_pSwapChain = NULL;
ID3D11RenderTargetView* g_pRenderTargetView = NULL;
ID3D11VertexShader*     g_pVertexShader = NULL;
ID3D11PixelShader*      g_pPixelShader = NULL;
ID3D11InputLayout*      g_pVertexLayout = NULL;

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Forward declarations
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
HRESULT InitWindow( HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow );
HRESULT InitDevice();
void CleanupDevice();
LRESULT CALLBACK    WndProc( HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM );
void Render();

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Entry point to the program. Initializes everything and goes into a message processing 
// loop. Idle time is used to render the scene.
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
int WINAPI wWinMain( HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPWSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow )
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER( hPrevInstance );
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER( lpCmdLine );

    if( FAILED( InitWindow( hInstance, nCmdShow ) ) )
        return 0;

    if( FAILED( InitDevice() ) )
    {
        CleanupDevice();
        return 0;
    }

    // Main message loop
    MSG msg = {0};
    while( WM_QUIT != msg.message )
    {
        if( PeekMessage( &msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE ) )
        {
            TranslateMessage( &msg );
            DispatchMessage( &msg );
        }
        else
        {
            Render();
        }
    }

    CleanupDevice();

    return ( int )msg.wParam;
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Register class and create window
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
HRESULT InitWindow( HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow )
{
    // Register class
    WNDCLASSEX wcex;
    wcex.cbSize = sizeof( WNDCLASSEX );
    wcex.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wcex.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wcex.hInstance = hInstance;
    wcex.hIcon = LoadIcon( hInstance, ( LPCTSTR )IDI_TUTORIAL1 );
    wcex.hCursor = LoadCursor( NULL, IDC_ARROW );
    wcex.hbrBackground = ( HBRUSH )( COLOR_WINDOW + 1 );
    wcex.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wcex.lpszClassName = L"TutorialWindowClass";
    wcex.hIconSm = LoadIcon( wcex.hInstance, ( LPCTSTR )IDI_TUTORIAL1 );
    if( !RegisterClassEx( &wcex ) )
        return E_FAIL;

    // Create window
    g_hInst = hInstance;
    RECT rc = { 0, 0, 640, 480 };
    AdjustWindowRect( &rc, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, FALSE );
    g_hWnd = CreateWindow( L"TutorialWindowClass", L"Direct3D 11 Tutorial 2: Rendering a Triangle",
                           WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
                           CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, rc.right - rc.left, rc.bottom - rc.top, NULL, NULL, hInstance,
                           NULL );
    if( !g_hWnd )
        return E_FAIL;
Model *model=0;
     //model=new Model;
    model[0].Init(g_pd3dDevice,g_pImmediateContext);
    ShowWindow( g_hWnd, nCmdShow );

    return S_OK;
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Helper for compiling shaders with D3DX11
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
HRESULT CompileShaderFromFile( WCHAR* szFileName, LPCSTR szEntryPoint, LPCSTR szShaderModel, ID3DBlob** ppBlobOut )
{
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;

    DWORD dwShaderFlags = D3DCOMPILE_ENABLE_STRICTNESS;
#if defined( DEBUG ) || defined( _DEBUG )
    // Set the D3DCOMPILE_DEBUG flag to embed debug information in the shaders.
    // Setting this flag improves the shader debugging experience, but still allows 
    // the shaders to be optimized and to run exactly the way they will run in 
    // the release configuration of this program.
    dwShaderFlags |= D3DCOMPILE_DEBUG;
#endif

    ID3DBlob* pErrorBlob;
    hr = D3DX11CompileFromFile( szFileName, NULL, NULL, szEntryPoint, szShaderModel, 
        dwShaderFlags, 0, NULL, ppBlobOut, &pErrorBlob, NULL );
    if( FAILED(hr) )
    {
        if( pErrorBlob != NULL )
            OutputDebugStringA( (char*)pErrorBlob->GetBufferPointer() );
        if( pErrorBlob ) pErrorBlob->Release();
        return hr;
    }
    if( pErrorBlob ) pErrorBlob->Release();

    return S_OK;
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Create Direct3D device and swap chain
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
HRESULT InitDevice()
{
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;

    RECT rc;
    GetClientRect( g_hWnd, &rc );
    UINT width = rc.right - rc.left;
    UINT height = rc.bottom - rc.top;

    UINT createDeviceFlags = 0;
#ifdef _DEBUG
    createDeviceFlags |= D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG;
#endif

    D3D_DRIVER_TYPE driverTypes[] =
    {
        D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE,
        D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_WARP,
        D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_REFERENCE,
    };
    UINT numDriverTypes = ARRAYSIZE( driverTypes );

    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL featureLevels[] =
    {
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0,
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_1,
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_0,
    };
    UINT numFeatureLevels = ARRAYSIZE( featureLevels );

    DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC sd;
    ZeroMemory( &sd, sizeof( sd ) );
    sd.BufferCount = 1;
    sd.BufferDesc.Width = width;
    sd.BufferDesc.Height = height;
    sd.BufferDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
    sd.BufferDesc.RefreshRate.Numerator = 60;
    sd.BufferDesc.RefreshRate.Denominator = 1;
    sd.BufferUsage = DXGI_USAGE_RENDER_TARGET_OUTPUT;
    sd.OutputWindow = g_hWnd;
    sd.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
    sd.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
    sd.Windowed = TRUE;

    for( UINT driverTypeIndex = 0; driverTypeIndex < numDriverTypes; driverTypeIndex++ )
    {
        g_driverType = driverTypes[driverTypeIndex];
        hr = D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain( NULL, g_driverType, NULL, createDeviceFlags, featureLevels, numFeatureLevels,
                                            D3D11_SDK_VERSION, &sd, &g_pSwapChain, &g_pd3dDevice, &g_featureLevel, &g_pImmediateContext );
        if( SUCCEEDED( hr ) )
            break;
    }
    if( FAILED( hr ) )
        return hr;

    // Create a render target view
    ID3D11Texture2D* pBackBuffer = NULL;
    hr = g_pSwapChain->GetBuffer( 0, __uuidof( ID3D11Texture2D ), ( LPVOID* )&pBackBuffer );
    if( FAILED( hr ) )
        return hr;

    hr = g_pd3dDevice->CreateRenderTargetView( pBackBuffer, NULL, &g_pRenderTargetView );
    pBackBuffer->Release();
    if( FAILED( hr ) )
        return hr;

    g_pImmediateContext->OMSetRenderTargets( 1, &g_pRenderTargetView, NULL );

    // Setup the viewport
    D3D11_VIEWPORT vp;
    vp.Width = (FLOAT)width;
    vp.Height = (FLOAT)height;
    vp.MinDepth = 0.0f;
    vp.MaxDepth = 1.0f;
    vp.TopLeftX = 0;
    vp.TopLeftY = 0;
    g_pImmediateContext->RSSetViewports( 1, &vp );

    // Compile the vertex shader
    ID3DBlob* pVSBlob = NULL;
    hr = CompileShaderFromFile( L"Tutorial02.fx", "VS", "vs_4_0", &pVSBlob );
    if( FAILED( hr ) )
    {
        MessageBox( NULL,
                    L"The FX file cannot be compiled.  Please run this executable from the directory that contains the FX file.", L"Error", MB_OK );
        return hr;
    }

    // Create the vertex shader
    hr = g_pd3dDevice->CreateVertexShader( pVSBlob->GetBufferPointer(), pVSBlob->GetBufferSize(), NULL, &g_pVertexShader );
    if( FAILED( hr ) )
    {   
        pVSBlob->Release();
        return hr;
    }

    // Define the input layout
    D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC layout[] =
    {
        { "POSITION", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT, 0, 0, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0 },
    };
    UINT numElements = ARRAYSIZE( layout );

    // Create the input layout
    hr = g_pd3dDevice->CreateInputLayout( layout, numElements, pVSBlob->GetBufferPointer(),
                                          pVSBlob->GetBufferSize(), &g_pVertexLayout );
    pVSBlob->Release();
    if( FAILED( hr ) )
        return hr;

    // Set the input layout
    g_pImmediateContext->IASetInputLayout( g_pVertexLayout );

    // Compile the pixel shader
    ID3DBlob* pPSBlob = NULL;
    hr = CompileShaderFromFile( L"Tutorial02.fx", "PS", "ps_4_0", &pPSBlob );
    if( FAILED( hr ) )
    {
        MessageBox( NULL,
                    L"The FX file cannot be compiled.  Please run this executable from the directory that contains the FX file.", L"Error", MB_OK );
        return hr;
    }

    // Create the pixel shader
    hr = g_pd3dDevice->CreatePixelShader( pPSBlob->GetBufferPointer(), pPSBlob->GetBufferSize(), NULL, &g_pPixelShader );
    pPSBlob->Release();
    if( FAILED( hr ) )
        return hr;  
    return S_OK;
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Clean up the objects we've created
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void CleanupDevice()
{
    if( g_pImmediateContext ) g_pImmediateContext->ClearState();

//    if( g_pVertexBuffer ) g_pVertexBuffer->Release();
    if( g_pVertexLayout ) g_pVertexLayout->Release();
    if( g_pVertexShader ) g_pVertexShader->Release();
    if( g_pPixelShader ) g_pPixelShader->Release();
    if( g_pRenderTargetView ) g_pRenderTargetView->Release();
    if( g_pSwapChain ) g_pSwapChain->Release();
    if( g_pImmediateContext ) g_pImmediateContext->Release();
    if( g_pd3dDevice ) g_pd3dDevice->Release();
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Called every time the application receives a message
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc( HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam )
{
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc;

    switch( message )
    {
        case WM_PAINT:
            hdc = BeginPaint( hWnd, &ps );
            EndPaint( hWnd, &ps );
            break;

        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage( 0 );
            break;

        default:
            return DefWindowProc( hWnd, message, wParam, lParam );
    }

    return 0;
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Render a frame
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void Render()
{
    // Clear the back buffer 
    float ClearColor[4] = { 0.0f, 0.125f, 0.3f, 1.0f }; // red,green,blue,alpha
    g_pImmediateContext->ClearRenderTargetView( g_pRenderTargetView, ClearColor );

    // Render a triangle
    g_pImmediateContext->VSSetShader( g_pVertexShader, NULL, 0 );
    g_pImmediateContext->PSSetShader( g_pPixelShader, NULL, 0 );
    g_pImmediateContext->Draw( 3, 0 );

    // Present the information rendered to the back buffer to the front buffer (the screen)
    g_pSwapChain->Present( 0, 0 );
} здесь
```

Comment: Ну а что ты читаешь?

Comment: Читаю из файла это:

`0.0  0.5 0.5
 0.5 -0.5 0.5
-0.5 -0.5 1.5`

И всё это пытаемся забить в буфер вершин.

Comment: Формат всмысле, тхт?

Comment: К вопросу о номерах строк в листингах...

Comment: расширение не имеет значения. 3 строки по 3 значения (просто в комментарии это всё выравнялось в одну строку). Я уже делал так загрузку одного полигона. Теперь пытаюсь сделать класс для загрузки полигонов и вот столкнулся с этой "обидой"

Comment: "К вопросу о номерах строк в листингах..." - не внял. Можно более расширеный вопрос?

Comment: Так у тебяж g_pVertexBuffer пустой ?!

Comment: g_pd3dDevice тоже пустой  
Ты ведь весь этот код скопипастил от куда то ?! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Отсутствует инициализация g_pd3dDevice

```
ID3D11Device*           g_pd3dDevice = NULL;
```

В дальнейшем вы пытаетесь разыменовывать NULL

```
g_pd3dDevice->CreateBuffer( &bd, &InitData, &g_pVertexBuffer );
```

Если Вы предоставили полный код, то для решения данной проблемы следует в указатель занести адрес, где будет расположен элемент типа ID3D11Device